# How to get the date difference in outside of the loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have multiple start dates in different div. If the div date from the current date is more than 365 days, I need to hide the pay button. Orelse I need to show. I want to do this in angularjs.

1) If first div date differnece is less than 365 days I need to show pay button. Else I need to hide.

2) Same as for all div. I have more than 50 div's are there.

[image]

```js
{
date:[{
  date:"01/01/2016"
}
{
  date:"01/01/2016"
}
{
  date:"01/01/2016"
}
{
  date:"01/01/2016"
}
{
  date:"01/01/2016"
}
{
  date:"01/01/2016"
}

]
}
   var date2 = new Date();
   var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
   var diffdate = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
   
   for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    var date1 = data[i].date;
    var date2 = new Date();
   var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
   var diffdate = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
   $scope.differnece = diffdate.map(Number) 
    if($scope.differnece > 365){
     $("$pay").hide();
   }else{
     $("#pay").show();

  }
   }
```

```html
<button id="pay">Pay</button>
```

Here inside loop I got the difference between all two dates. But Please help me how can I write condition based on each div difference date.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller,

first initialize

```
 $scope.showButton = true;   //To show the button initially. Else set it to  false.
```

**Edited:**

Since you are using multiple divisions,

```
 if($scope.differnece > 365){
   if($scope.showButton) {
       $scope.showButton = false;
   }
 }
```

In yout template, use ng-show directive.

```
  <button id="pay" ng-show="showButton">Pay</button>
```

when the value of the showButton is true, the button is shown and when it is set to false the button will hide.

Comment: For one div it will work. But I have more than 50. So I need to write loop. If I write your condition it will take only the last value.

Comment: I have edited the answer  as 

if($scope.differnece > 365){
   if($scope.showButton) {
       $scope.showButton = false;
   }
 }